# Sharing asyncio.Queue with another thread or process

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, asynchronous, python-asyncio, template-matching

I've recently converted my old template matching program to asyncio and I have a situation where one of my coroutines relies on a blocking method (`processing_frame`).

I want to run that method in a seperate thread or process whenever the coroutine **that calls that method** (`analyze_frame`) gets an item from the shared `asyncio.Queue()`

I'm not sure if that's possible or worth it performance wise since I have very little experience with threading and multiprocessing

```
import cv2
import datetime
import argparse
import os
import asyncio

#   Making CLI
if not os.path.exists("frames"):
    os.makedirs("frames")

t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", required=True,
                help="path to our file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

threshold = .2
death_count = 0
was_found = False
template = cv2.imread('youdied.png')
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
frames_to_analyze = asyncio.Queue()


def main():
    length = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    tasks = []
    for _ in range(int(length / 50)):
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(read_frame(50, frames_to_analyze)))
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(analyze_frame(threshold, template, frames_to_analyze)))
    final_task = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    loop.run_until_complete(final_task)

    dt = datetime.datetime.now() - t0
    print("App exiting, total time: {:,.2f} sec.".format(dt.total_seconds()))

    print(f"Deaths registered: {death_count}")


async def read_frame(frames, frames_to_analyze):
    global vidcap
    for _ in range(frames-1):
        vidcap.grab()

    else:
        current_frame = vidcap.read()[1]
    print("Read 50 frames")
    await frames_to_analyze.put(current_frame)


async def analyze_frame(threshold, template, frames_to_analyze):
    global vidcap
    global was_found
    global death_count
    frame = await frames_to_analyze.get()
    is_found = processing_frame(frame)
    if was_found and not is_found:
        death_count += 1
        await writing_to_file(death_count, frame)
    was_found = is_found


def processing_frame(frame):
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(frame, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    max_val = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)[1]
    is_found = max_val >= threshold
    print(is_found)
    return is_found


async def writing_to_file(death_count, frame):
    cv2.imwrite(f"frames/frame{death_count}.jpg", frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried using [unsync](https://github.com/alex-sherman/unsync) but without much success
I would get something along the lines of

> with self._rlock:
>   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `processing_frame` is a blocking function, you should call it with `await loop.run_in_executor(None, processing_frame, frame)`. That will submit the function to a thread pool and allow the event loop to proceed with doing other things until the call function completes.

The same goes for calls such as `cv2.imwrite`. As written, `writing_to_file` is *not* truly asynchronous, despite being defined with `async def`. This is because it doesn't await anything, so once its execution starts, it will proceed to the end without ever suspending. In that case one could as well make it a normal function in the first place, to make it obvious what's going on.